# Problem installing keras and support for a LTSM RNN

Tags: python, keras

I have a problem installing keras in the Python version 3.12 using VSCode in an Asus Notebook running Windows 11. The final following message appears on the screen:

```
       File "C:\Users\João\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\subprocess.py", line 413, in check_call
          raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
      subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['cmake', 'C:\\Users\\João\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-ll8f_kl9\\dm-tree_85d7473578b94b2bb03305ca6775c834\\tree', '-DPython3_ROOT_DIR=C:\\Users\\João\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312', '-DPython3_EXECUTABLE=C:\\Users\\João\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\python.exe', '-DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=C:\\Users\\João\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-ll8f_kl9\\dm-tree_85d7473578b94b2bb03305ca6775c834\\build\\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312', '-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for dm-tree
  Running setup.py clean for dm-tree
Failed to build dm-tree
ERROR: Could not build wheels for dm-tree, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

Can anybody help me, please?

I already tried to downgrade the python version. I could successfully install tensorflow. I already tried the cmd commands, tried installing nvidia cuda to support the RNN environment, but I am going crazy right now. I have this software to present in college at the end of the week, and I am hours along trying to install keras and can't do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You appear to be using Windows but [Keras 3 is compatible with Linux and MacOS systems](https://pypi.org/project/keras/).

**For Windows users, it is recommended to use WSL2 to run Keras**. To install a local development version:

1. Install dependencies:
   `pip install -r requirements.txt`
2. Run installation command from the root directory:
   `python pip_build.py --install`

Remember to use a supported Python version i.e. 3.9 - 3.11.